# CSS, menu:active not working

Tags: css, menu, hover

I have a simple menu:

```
<ul id="menu2">
    <li> <a href="index.php?id=home">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="index.php?id=about">About us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="index.php?id=contacts">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in css file I have:

```
#menu2 {
    background: black;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 220px;
}
#menu2 li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu2 a {
    background: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu2 a:hover {
    background: black url("../images/select.png") left center no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px 16px;
}

#menu2 a:active {
    background: black url("../images/select.png") left center no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px 16px;
}
```

Everything works well except for `#menu2 a:active` not working at all while `#menu2 a:hover` (with same rules) works well. What is the problem? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide more details of what exactly is not working and/or a demo.  Looking at the code it appears to be fine.

The :active state refers to when a link is pressed, so if you press and hold your mouse button down on your menu item it should be working as expected since hover works active has the same properties.

A link with :active will not remain that way when your on the page it links too, it reverts back to a normal link.

Comment: oh, thank you! So how do I do that when the link is pressed it has different style?

Comment: It sounds like you want the link to have a different style on page load, for example if you click the 'About Us' menu item and go to the page you want it show as say highlighted to let the user know they are on that page.  In which case you need to that through server side code or you can use javascript and parse the current URL and comparing it with the menu URL's,  when a match is found then apply a different style to it.

Answer (score 3):

It is working as expected. I colored the *active state* red.
Try clicking on en element and hold the button down. The background will be red.

You don't see a change, because you CSS for `hover` and `active` are identical!

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/dqH3F/1/

**Sample contains**

```
#menu2 a:active {
    background: red url("../images/select.png") left center no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px 16px;
}
```

Comment: To clarify: since the :hover and :active rules are exactly the same, you won't see any difference between hovering and then clicking - as made visible in Smamatti's example, when using different rules. (Edit: good update of the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

Your background for :hover and :active in the code above is the exact same.

Are you trying to set a background x and y position on active?

Without image background and different colors (for testing) your code works fine: see here http://jsfiddle.net/stursby/9Pccb/